# Why is my angular factory provider code throwing an error on the injected $window object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I a trying to access the browser `$window` object in angular but I keep getting this error `Error: $window is undefined` even when this same code works perfectly in a `service provider` code:

Here is the `sessionFactory` code:

```
angular.module('app').factory('sessionFactory', [
  '$window',
  'formattingFactory',
  sessionFactory
]);

var myFormattingFactory = new formattingFactory();

function sessionFactory($window, formattingFactory) {

  function formatText(text) {
    myFormattingFactory.format(text);
  }

  return {
    save: function(key, value) {
      $window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, formatText(value));
    },
    get: function(key) {
      return $window.sessionStorage.getItem(key);

    },
    clear: function() {
      $window.sessionStorage.clear();
    }

  }
}
```

And this is my `sessionController` code:

```
angular.module('app').controller('sessionController', [
  'sessionService',
  'sessionFactory',
  sessionController
]);
var mySessionFactory = new sessionFactory();


function sessionController(sessionService, sessionFactory) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.getFactorySession = getFactorySession;
  vm.setFactorySession = setFactorySession;
  vm.clearFactorySession = clearFactorySession;  

  vm.getServiceSession = function() {
    vm.model = {
      name: sessionService.get('name'),
      nickname: sessionService.get('nickname'),
      status: 'Retrieved by service on' + new Date()
    }
  }

  vm.setServiceSession = function() {
    sessionService.save('name', vm.model.name);
    sessionService.save('nickname', vm.model.nickname);
    vm.getServiceSession();
  }
  vm.clearServiceSession = function() {
    sessionService.clear();
    vm.getServiceSession();
  }

  function getFactorySession() {
    vm.model = {
      name: mySessionFactory.get('name'),
      nickname: mySessionFactory.get('nickname'),
      status: 'Retrieved by Factory on ' + new Date()
    };
  }

  function setFactorySession() {
    mySessionFactory.save('name', vm.model.name);
    mySessionFactory.save('nickname', vm.model.nickname);
    getFactorySession();
  }

  function clearFactorySession() {
    mySessionFactory.clear();
    getFactorySession();
  }    

}
```

And this is the code for the `sessionService` that works great and can access the browser `$window` object without any error:

```
angular.module('app').service('sessionService', [
  '$window',
  sessionService
]);

function sessionService($window) {
  this.save = save;
  this.get = get;
  this.clear = clear;

  function save(key, value) {
    $window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
  }

  function get(key) {
    return $window.sessionStorage.getItem(key)
  }

  function clear() {
    $window.sessionStorage.clear();
  }
}
```

This is the `formattingFactory` code:

```
angular.module('app').factory('formattingFactory', [
  formattingFactory
]);

function formattingFactory() {
  function format(text) {
    this.text = text;
    if ((text.trim().length % 2) === 0) {
      return text.toUpperCase();
    } else {
      return text.toLowerCase();
    }
  }

  return {
    format: format
  }

}
```

Comment: sessionFactory is incorrectly annotated for DI, it expects 2 deps but has only 1 param. It is formattingFactory that should be undefined, but in your error it's $window. This means that the code you've posted differs from the one you're using.

Comment: @estus, I don't get the different part mentioned by you but I have added the `formattingFactory` code and I also have a html page that calls the methods. And if you could give the correction for the sessionFactory it might help me understand the error.

Comment: Ok I get the `2 dep` so I now have the update seen above.

Comment: `var myFormattingFactory = new formattingFactory()` should be reside inside inside factory function .

Comment: @estus Inside sessionFactory or formattingFactory, please note nobby taking angular course, forgive my ignorance

Comment: sessionFactory. You're getting formattingFactory as an argument there. Otherwise it's undefined.

Comment: Is this `function formatText(text) {
    var myFormattingFactory = new formattingFactory();
    myFormattingFactory.format(text);
  }` what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

`myFormattingFactory` is a dependency of `sessionFactory` and should reside inside its factory function:

```
angular.module('app').factory('sessionFactory', [
  '$window',
  'formattingFactory',
  sessionFactory
]);

function sessionFactory($window, formattingFactory) {
  // formattingFactory is an object and can be used here
  ...
```

`formattingFactory` service instance is passed as an argument there. It is undefined otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for your time but I get this error using your code `TypeError: formattingFactory is not a constructor`

Comment: Because it's not a constructor indeed. It's an object that is returned by `formattingFactory` service. It's misleading to give these services names with `factory` suffix - because injected values are not factory functions. I'd suggest to revisit AngularJS DI basics and the difference between providers.

Comment: Funny you would say that as I am currently following a tutorial that has the code as you see it here. Take out the `formattingFactory` code and that's how the `sessionFactory` is made to look. I initially started having issues with the `$window` object when creating the `sessionFactory` provider. This same code (i.e. the sessionFactory without the formattingFactory` works great in a sessionService provider but refuses to work in sessionFactory. I have double checked my code as I have it as expected from the tutorial